# For OpenSSH legacy hardware access, ssh-rsa is used as preferred host key algorithm only if -oHostkeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa is included on command line

Tags: ssh, command-line, key-authentication

The connection is for WD MyCloud [OS3], local network only as cloud access has been closed. Sshd_config contains:

```
HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
```

but the verbose log for OpenSSH_8.8p1 reports:

```
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256

...

debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: (no match)
Unable to negotiate with 'hostIP' port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
```

Only when -oHostkeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa is supplied on the command line does the  log show :

```
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa

...

debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none

...

debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

and the connection succeeds. Ultimately, I need to call ssh from rSYNC. Although rSYNC does allow ssh options, I haven't found anything in the ssh documentation to explain why this can't be handled by the config files.

Comment: You need to put this in `ssh_config` on the client machine, since it's the `ssh` client that needs configuring.  `sshd_config` is for the server.

Comment: (@StephenHarris) or `~/.ssh/config` if you only want/need it for some user(s) (or another file specified with `-F`, but that's as much work as specifying `-oHostKey...`)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should understand what this option does and why you have to specify it.  The traditional `ssh-rsa` and `ssh-dsa` algorithms use SHA-1 for signatures, either with RSA or with DSA.  SHA-1 is presently considered very weak and practical attacks have been demonstrated on it.  In addition, DSA in OpenSSH is limited to 1024-bit keys, which provide an inadequate 80-bit security level (128 bits is the minimum recommended level).

As such, OpenSSH has disabled these algorithms because they are insecure, and if you are using them, the security of your connection cannot be assured.  If possible, you should upgrade the firmware on your device to a newer version that will have appropriate patches applied.  You should do this anyway, since if the version of the SSH server is old, it will probably have other security problems as well.

If you really cannot upgrade and you must continue to use this, then you can specify the configuration in your `~/.ssh/config`.  Assuming the IP is `192.0.2.3`, you can write:

```
Host 192.0.2.3
    HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

Then, when rsync calls ssh via this IP, it should set the algorithms correctly.  If you use a hostname instead of an IP, use that in the `Host` directive instead.

Comment: "_use that in the Host directive instead_" there's no harm in having both IP and name on the `Host` line

Comment: Nit: `ssh-keygen` will only generate DSA-1024, but `ssh` and `sshd` will use larger if you generate another way -- but still with SHA-1, which is now considered taboo and cootie-infested even though it's actually secure when signing data (like SSH's exchange hash) that adversary cannot control.