# SSH returns Unable to negotiate ....: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to SSH into my Qhora router

> Unable to negotiate with 192.168.100.1 port 22200: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa

```
$ ssh 192.168.100.1 -p 22200
Unable to negotiate with 192.168.100.1 port 22200: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa
```

How can I get SSH working?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/682777/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/726423/117549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `192.168.100.1` is your ip. Alternatively, you can set an alias, like `laxssh` that enables the option with `-o`

```
alias laxssh=ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa
```

If you want this to be permanent, you can white list just one host to be more lack `~/.ssh/config`,

```
Host 192.168.100.1
    PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
    HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

I would be careful on assuming that any IP should support ssh-rsa as it was disabled because it's insecure. I would prefer the `laxssh` alias.